# RX java/Android how to i achieve This toast on every click using debounce operator

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-android

I have this ImageView which on clicked should Show toast and also making api on click of the image View, so I decided to use Debounce operator in Rx
but now thost is not visible on every click. below is the code

```
cartSubscriptionDecrement = RxView.clicks(holder.databinding
            .cartQuantityLayout.ivDecreaseQuantity)
            .debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe { next ->
   cartQuantityEvent.onCartQuantityDecremented(cartSubscriptionDecrement!!)
            }
```

I need to show toast on every single click of imageView.

I tried to have a separate onclick method for Image View but during debugging I found that  the control is never coming to onclick method this is my another onclick method

How do I achieve this toast on every click while not making an api call in every click (make use of Debounce operator).

Comment: holder.deleteCartIcon!!.setOnClickListener {
            v ->
            Log.e("clicked","clicked")
        }   another onclick method is above

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do what you're asking. I've included the simplest below, but will need to think more about potential side effects from using doOnNext.

[The code for this example lives on Github here if you're interested in running the app.](https://github.com/lustigdev/StackOverflowProblems/blob/stackoverflow/toast-every-debounce-api-call/app/src/main/java/com/example/michaellustig/dynamicnetworkrequests/MainActivity.java) Just realized the package name is wrong, but the example will run just fine.

The most relevant code to the example is below. The key is that you'll need to debounce *after* you show the Toast rather than before.

```
RxView.clicks(image1)
            .doOnNext(imageClickedEvent -> {
                // Show toast every time onNext is called (this will also log to LogCat)
                showToast();
            })
            .debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe(clickEvent -> {
                makeApiCall();
            });
```

> I tried to have a separate onclick method for Image View but during debugging I found that the control is never coming to onclick method this is my another onclick method

I believe this is the case because RxClicks sets a listener on the ImageView, and that occurs **after** the framework sets the onClick listener and you can only have one `OnClickListener` on a `View` if I recall correctly. So what's happening is the `RxView.clicks(imageView)` is receiving the click event rather than the method you created separately.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply ".subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())" to all RxBinding events, such as "RxView.clicks()"